# Vanishing/exploding gradient for RNN

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

Background: I'm currently training a recurrent neural network for text sentiment analysis.
The data set is a collection of sentences which are binary classified as either positive or negative.

Problem: The neural network works fine (i.e. loss is decreasing over time) with smaller sentences (less than 3-4 words), but for larger sentences, the cost rockets up until the whole program breaks down.

Would this be an example of the vanishing/exploding gradient problem?
If so, which of the two is it, and how can I fix it?

I thought that, for simple RNN's, the vanishing gradient problem is not a big issue. Typically, how many time steps could an RNN handle well without using some sort of LTSM/GRU architectures?

EDIT1: I'm not using LSTM or GRU architectures for this network.
EDIT2: I think it might be a vanishing gradient problem, because the gradient is approaching zero, especially for longer sentences.
EDIT3: I've noticed that, when I perform gradient checking, the difference between the backpropagation gradient and numerically calculated gradient is inconsistent. 
Sometimes they are very similar:

```
Estimated gradient: -0.03798713081426541
Actual gradient: -0.03798713058052253

Estimated gradient: 0.09233359214502745
Actual gradient: 0.09233359179904115

Estimated gradient: 0.0769223445411249
Actual gradient: 0.07692234419615167

Estimated gradient: 0.12397360958732451
Actual gradient: 0.12397360903699521
```

*These aren't adjacent checks - just hand-picked examples of good gradient checks.
Other times, they are very different:

```
Estimated gradient: -4.0245362598057e-07
Actual gradient: 3.4145999078185475e-12
Gradient Check ERROR
Relative error: 1.0

Estimated gradient: -4.241412776551101e-08
Actual gradient: -2.1161111156415113e-16
Gradient Check ERROR
Relative error: 0.9999999900216686

Estimated gradient: 0.0
Actual gradient: -4.450453565269026e-32
Gradient Check ERROR
Relative error: 1.0
```

Comment: Are you using an LSTM or GRU architecture? Maybe add some additional info about your hyper parameters.

Comment: without being an expert at it I would bet for exploding gradient rather than vanishing if it has to be one of the two. I think vanishing gradients just makes your training stagnate while exploding make it diverge. Exploding gradients are often dealt with by applying a clipping threshold.

Comment: Generally clipping gradient can make things better. Also cost skyrocketing can be caused by to big learn rate sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-implementing the RNN with a LSTM architecture solved the problem. Vanishing gradients was the issue.